# File upload error with Nginx, Node JS (multer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, upload, multer

When uploading a file using node JS and expanding Multer returns error:

```
code: "EACCES"
errno: -13
path: "directory/filename.txt"
storageErrors: []
syscall: "open"
```

Storage:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './files/')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname.split(" ").join(""))
    }
});
```

I think this is due to the fact that there is no user access to the directory on the server, but I can't find a solution to solve it.

Comment: did you mkdir the files directory ?

Comment: try to chmod 777. or chown to the right user

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  chmod 777 helped and the file began to load. But will not be the reason that each user can have access to this directory?

Comment: yes, but do you have many users on your machine ? why is your node process launched as another user than the directory ?